# TFS 2008 upgrade to 2010 failed upgrade pre tfs 2010 database failed

Tags: tfs, upgrade

I'm currently in the process of upgrading the TFS server from 2008 to 2010 for trial. So basically, here is the following steps i have done:

- back up database
- restore the database on a new db server, DB.
- install TFS 2010 on another server, TFS.
- select the upgrade scenario
- failed with the following error:

> [Info   @00:33:55.170] [2010-07-27
>   07:43:48Z][Informational] Step
>   Performer: Build
>
> [Info   @00:33:55.170] [2010-07-27
>   07:43:48Z][Informational] Step Type:
>   MigrateBuildDefinitionSchedules
>
> [Info   @00:33:55.170] [2010-07-27
>   07:43:48Z][Informational] Step Data
>   Text:
>
> [Error  @00:33:55.170] [2010-07-27
>   07:43:49Z][Error] Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> [Info   @00:33:55.170] [2010-07-27
>   07:43:49Z][Informational]
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationJobSchedule.Validate(String
>   topLevelParamName, Int32
>   minimumScheduleInterval)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationJobDefinition.Validate(String
>   topLevelParamName, Int32
>   minimumJobInterval)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationJobService.UpdateJobDefinitions(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   requestContext, IEnumerable`1
>   jobsToDelete, IEnumerable`1
>   jobUpdates, Boolean allowRunOnceJobs,
>   Boolean repairQueueOnly)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.UpdateBuildDefinitions(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   requestContext, IList`1 updates)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.BuildStepPerformer.MigrateBuildDefinitionSchedules(String
>   stepData, ServicingContext
>   servicingContext, Boolean
>   validateOnly)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.IStepPerformer.PerformStep(String
>   servicingOperation, String stepType,
>   String stepData, ServicingContext
>   servicingContext)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep
>   step, ServicingContext
>   servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup
>   group, ServicingOperation
>   servicingOperation, Boolean
>   validateOnly)
>
> [Info   @00:33:55.170] [2010-07-27
>   07:43:49Z] Servicing step Migrate
>   Build Definition Schedules failed.
>   (ServicingOperation:
>   UpgradePreTfs2010Databases; Step
>   group: Upgrade.TfsTeamBuild)
>
> [Info   @00:33:55.170] [2010-07-27
>   07:43:49Z][Informational] Clearing
>   dictionary, removing all items.
>
> [Error  @00:33:55.170] The servicing
>   operation failed.

I can't move on and have no idea what went wrong.

Please help.

Thanks,

Chen

Comment: Thanks Robaticus. Didn't aware we can do that fancy thing :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your TFS 2008 server updated to Service Pack 1?

If not you need to update first. YOu can try following:

http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/05/03/upgrading-team-foundation-server-2008-to-2010.aspx